# Struggling to enable Hyper-V on Windows 10, AMD Ryzen: "A hypervisor has been detected"

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, docker, hyper-v, amd-ryzen

- Gigabyte Aorus X470 Gaming 7 WIFI
- AMD Ryzen 2700X
- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit v. 1903
- BIOS F31
- AMD Chipset driver v. 19

I have enabled `SVM` in the BIOS.
I have installed `Hyper-V` in Windows components.

I'm running `msinfo32` and expect to see four items related to Hyper-V. Instead, I see: *"A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed."*

How do I enable Hyper-V??

PS My goal is to run Docker natively, without VirtualBox. When I try to setup Kinematic, it says:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web-insiderplat_pc/cant-install-hyper-v-or-third-party-virtualization/1c233e75-8219-4e74-ac6a-2e604f52709c

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thx, but it looks irrelevant. None of the registry entries they suggested to delete existed in the first place. And I don't have a "secure boot" option in my BIOS.

Comment: If you see A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed." then Hyper-V is enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting Hyper-V Manager and setting up a virtual machine has proved that Hyper-V is working correctly.

After that, Docker started working! Not sure if it's a coincidence.

UPD: Docker wasn't working for me because legacy VirtualBox-driven Docker had been installed and overwritten env vars. Hyper-V-driven Docker was mislead by those env vars and failed to start properly.

Deleting legacy Docker and removing its env vars by hand resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have message showing like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN0Sy.png) saying

"**A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.**"

simply means that you have already running Hyper-V currently.

You no need to go for other configurations.